# Term for neologisms created to distinguish between new and old technologies

Tags: phrase-requests

For example:

book -> paper book, e-book

phone -> telephone, smartphone

Term to describe the creation/modification of words because of the advent of technology.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence? Are you looking for a term for e.g. paper book, for e-book, for both paper book and e-book, or for the process that leads to the coinage of one or both terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [retronym](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym):

> A retronym is a newer name for an existing thing that differentiates the original form/version from a more recent one. It is thus a word or phrase created to avoid confusion between two types, whereas previously (before there were more than one type), no clarification was required.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: This is the term denoting the modified term for the older 'version', not the term for the new 'version'. As such, a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [iteration](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/iteration):

> A form, adaption, or version of something: the latest iteration of a popular app.

Another possibility is *digitization*, I suppose, but I'm not as fond of that term as I am with *iteration*.

As for *evolution*, well, frankly, I think the word is over-used. Those of us who did not grow up having a computer lab in elementary school, sometimes think the so-called technological advances are a kind of *devolution*. In some instances, instead of bringing us closer together, they tend to distance us, leaving us isolated in our own little digital cocoons.

Hey, call me a Luddite if you will, but I assure you I am not. The world wide web has opened up the world to so many people in so many beneficial ways, but there is also a downside to many of our technological advances and marvels. Nothing can ever completely take the place of face-to-face communication. During Covid, Zoom has been a real godsend. When Covid goes away (which I hope is soon), I think our society's priority should be to engage in community building.

We can start small.  One suggestion is to go on a digital-technology fast with a few close friends. Start by fasting for a short period of time, like an hour. During that hour, substitute high tech with low tech. Abandon ones and zeroes for one-on-one, in real-time.